# How to scroll within only part of a div

Tags: css

I'm trying to lock a div in place within another div, with a scrollable div beneath it when it overflows.

[image]

The problem I have is that the scrolling div has no way of knowing how big it can be before overflowing.

```css
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title{
  color: red;
}

.scroll-text{
  position: relative;
  
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  background-color: #979797;
}
```

```html
<div class="container scrollbar">
  <div class="title">
    Title: This tough guy shouldn't scroll
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-text">
    This is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. This is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for.
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I dynamically set the height of the scrolling div to always fit within it's parent, but still scroll?

Comment: I've been told that `canvas` can do this but have yet to find a way to do it.

Comment: position:sticky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you, this will help you.

```css
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title{
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  background-color: white;
}

.scrollbar{
  
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  background-color: #979797;
}
```

```html
<div class="container scrollbar">
  <div class="title">
    Title: This tough guy shouldn't scroll
  </div>
  <div class="scrollbar">
    This is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. This is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for. his is content purely designed to cause an overflow. No content in here has any purpose. Well, that is, besides it's purpose of being lengthy content. Is that a purpose? I guess so, but not one worthy of readying this arduous sentances for.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! You got what I mean exactly. I'm working on two things now: 1. Title should only be fixed within div, not the window. 2. Padding for scroll div should be dynamically calculated.

Comment: Update: Figured out that #2 is impossible just via css but still working on #1

Comment: I edited my answer now. I hope this will solve your both of problems :)

Comment: Nice! Yeah position sticky turned out to be the way to go. Thanks for your help @Osman Durdag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean.. but try making

```
.title {
    position: fixed;
}
```

or try to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in the outer div.

if you're trying to make it go over the title try

```
.title {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

idk not really clear what you want, like explain like your five..

Comment: Alright thanks for the feedback @KHaX. I'll try these suggestions and try and clarify the question.